# Styling the input type="file". How do I display the file path?

Tags: html, css, forms, file-upload

I have been trying to style an input type="file" field.
My button is styled but I can't seem to figure out how to get the filepath/file to show when the user selects the file to upload.
Can anyone out there help?

```css
.file-upload {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #707070;
  background: #A0A0A0;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-upload:hover {
  background: #2FA2FF;
}

.file-upload.focus {
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}

.file-upload input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: -1;
}

.file-upload span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: .45em;
}

.file-upload {
  height: 38px;
}

.file-upload,
.file-upload span {
  width: 160px;
}

.file-upload-status {
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 7px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #888;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
    <label class="file-upload"><span>Upload....</span><input name="uploadfile" type="file"> </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Information about the file itself as it relates to the user's OS is *protected* for security reasons.  You can get the name of the file, but not the path to where it is stored.

Comment: +1 to @cimmanon. In addition, whatever styling you go with, check it thoroughly on every browser that you want to support, because different browsers render the file control *very* differently from each other, and most of them have some kind of restrictions on how it can be styled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `change` event to the input field, and then just get it's `.value`.

Example (using jQuery):

```
$('input[name="uploadfile"]').change(function(){
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    alert(fileName);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hjNEC/2/

**EDIT**: Since the input field is hidden, and the file name is part of that, you're gonna have to display `fileName` on the page yourself.

Comment: Hi there...
Perfect ... I did this bit of JS


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('input[name="uploadfile"]').change(function(){
     var fileName = $(this).val();
     var subfileName = fileName.substring(0,16)+"...";
     $('#file-label').text(subfileName);
 });
});
</script>

So it displayed the filename over the "chose file" label of the button... thanks for you help....

HAPPY NEW YEAR!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new div to show the file path, and use Javascript in the `onchange` event to update the path displayed in the div whenever the user selects a file.

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
          <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" style="display:none" onchange="file_path_display.innerHTML=uploadfile.value"/>
          <span class="file-upload" onclick="uploadfile.click()" ondragdrop="uploadfile.dragdrop()">Upload....</span>
          <div id="file_path_display"></div>
     </div>
</form>
```