# Display File Path instead of just file name (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

When the user uploads their file, I want to display the filepath to that file.

NOTE: I, server, don't need  the filepath, I just want it to be displayed for the userinfo.

I know there are security concerns, but is it possible for it to be displayed only??

How would I do this?

so far:

```
        <form method="post" id="fileinfo" name="file" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
            <label>Select a file:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
        </form>

        <input type="button" value="Submit!!" id="myButton" />
```

so when they choose a file named test.txt,

my ui will display C://path//text.txt instead of just test.txt

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075420/styling-the-input-type-file-how-do-i-display-the-filepath)

Comment: Return the file path from a server sided scripts which will btw complete the upload

Comment: Tried that already, doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @valentin can you elaborate please? example would be nice

Comment: @user3773673 Ok I can write you a very detailed answer if you want. What is your server side script language? PHP?

Comment: java (restlet api/jersey)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to show the path

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAp2B/)

```
$('#file').change(function(){
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    $('#file_path').text(fileName);
});
```

The main problem is you can't edit the text on the file input, an alternative hack is show below:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAp2B/1/)

```
<div class="hide_text">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
</div>

.hide_text{
    display:inline-block;
    width:85px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```